# Can I filter the first character as String and second character as Int on an Array?

Tags: arrays, swift, filter

I imagine if it is possible to filter the first character as string and second character as Int? For example i have `M1: test M` and `B2: test M`on an Array.

**If I use this code:**

`filter{$0.contains("M")`

it is going to filter both `M1` and `B2` because on both of them there's the `M` character

And i'm thinking if there's any way to use something like `filter{$0.contains("M"+number)`, so it can filter only if there's a number after `M`.

Comment: .filter loops over a collection and returns an array containing only those elements that match an include condition.  When you say "filter as" do you mean puts them in the resulting collection as a String and an Int, for example: [String("M"), Int("2")!]?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can map your strings spliting the components separated by `":"`. Add a guard to filter the resulting elements prefix that starts with the desired letter, drop the first character of that prefix and coerce the resulting string to Int:

```
let array = ["M1: test","M2: test", "B2: test"]

let values: [Int] = array.flatMap {
    guard
        let prefix = $0.components(separatedBy: ":").first,
        prefix.first == "M" else { return nil }
        return Int(prefix.dropFirst()) ?? 0
}

print(values)  // "[1, 2]\n"
```

---

If you need to group them and trim the whitespaces:

```
let array = ["M1: test"," M2: test", "B2: test"]

let results = array.flatMap{ string -> (letter: String, value: Int, note: String)? in
    guard
        case let components = string.components(separatedBy: ":"),
        let prefix = components.first?.trimmingCharacters(in: .whitespaces),
        let suffix = components.last?.trimmingCharacters(in: .whitespaces),
        let letter = prefix.first else { return nil }
    return (String(letter), Int(prefix.dropFirst()) ?? 0, suffix)
}

print(results)  // "[(letter: "M", value: 1, note: "test"), (letter: "M", value: 2, note: "test"), (letter: "B", value: 2, note: "test")]\n"
```

---

If you just need the elements that hasPrefix "M":

```
let filtered = array.filter { $0.hasPrefix("M") }

print(filtered)  // "["M1: test", "M2: test"]\n"\n"
```

Comment: Yeah, but if it is `["M1: test M", "B2: test M", "M21: test A"]` it will print all of them right? Because there is everywhere an "M".

Comment: does is count whitespace inside a string? For example "  test" and "test". i think you can notice the difference.

Answer (score 0):

Try using this. Assuming your array of values is named data, split each value at the colon. Take the first substring and check for "M". If it is found return true otherwise false.

```
let data = ["M1: test M", "B2: test M", "M21: test A"]
let result = data.filter { $0.split(separator: ":").first?.contains("M") ?? false }
```

[image]

Comment: what it does? is it goes and filters only before `:`?

Comment: String has a property called hasPrefix exactly for that